# Group by...(mysql Join)

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I don't know how to sumarize colors for grouped cars.brand (distinct)...help please.

My question can't be explained  simply (a lot code) so look at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17bac6/2

I want:

```
brand   blue    red    green    black
volvo    320    7289    3313     1198
citroen  538    3286
seat    1245
audi    1076    2153    2595
bmv      135    5637     864      282
```

Tnx

Comment: what is you desired result?

Comment: sorry on my bad english...sum colors for distinct cars brand (audi, bmw...)

Comment: If you take out the total fields from the `GROUP BY` does that give you what you need? I.e. this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17bac6/24

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this should be what you're looking for.

```
SELECT  cars.brand,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blue 
  WHERE blue.prr = cars.id_p
) as "blue",
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM red 
  WHERE red.prr = cars.id_p
) as "red",
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM green 
  WHERE green.prr = cars.id_p
) as "green",
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM black 
  WHERE black.prr = cars.id_p
) as "black"
FROM    cars
WHERE   cars.user_id = 54 
AND     cars.pend between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31' 
GROUP BY cars.brand
```

If you designed that schema, please look up database normalization, and learn about relationships as the design isn't great (no offence intended)